# Would an app, featuring only a Webview component, get approved for the Store?

Tags: store

I am not a mobile app developer, but we do feature responsive design in our website which works very well on my Nokia Lumia. So if I were to make an app that only contains a fullscreen WebView component that loads the website, would that app be approved to get on the store?

Comment: It would have to be approved, but why would you want to create a 'fake' app?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft itself has published apps that are only a wrapper for a responsive website. It is a common practice and not against the rules, in fact there is a [how-to article](http://www.codeguru.com/win_mobile/client/your-mobile-website-as-a-windows-phone-app.html) showing how to do this.

Comment: Does that mean I am pretty much guaranteed that it will get approved?

Comment: @ImNotMike It doesn't mean that it is guaranteed, but the simpler your app is, the better chance you won't fail.